# Avoiding singletons and global variables - but what about caching, providers, controllers, ...?

Tags: caching, controller, tdd, singleton, global-variables

I'm currently "updating" my development knowledge especially on TDD principles by reading [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627), articles on the web and watching [videos](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam). Something that pops up everywhere is the warning, not to use global state variables as they make the system fragile and less easy to test and since singletons are not much better or rather the same, not to use those either.

Now I'm wondering: Can I actually be consistent about this?

- What about a cache, that the application uses so it doesn't have to look up frequently used database objects again and again? I NEED a single instance of that cache to be passed around, otherwise what would be the point?
- Another example are DAOs or as we call them providers. They do nothing but provide JPA database access for us but otherwise have no state. So why not make them singleton?
- And controllers in the web frontend? All they do is react to requests - again with no internal state.

Wouldn't it waste a lot of performance instantiating the latter two again and again? I'm sure there are a few more examples where this applies.

Maybe it's okay to use singletons, as long as they don't have any member variables except for finals?

And even if they have member variables but all of them are injected into them, it should be save to use them, as any object, singleton or not, can modify injected objects so it really doesn't make any difference.

I'm a bit confused about this whole "avoid singletons" business, I'm not even sure I fully understand the risks involved. But most of all I'd like to hear thoughts on the above examples, as those are the most common places in our application where we use singletons.

Thanks!

btw: we're using springs dependency injection, so how to do it is not my question, rather why avoid it and where it is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with Singletons is not so much the Singleton design pattern per se as their being overused under the covers as stateful global God objects all over applications.

That way of using them has 2 major drawbacks :

- Dependencies on singletons are hidden dependencies, and objects are tightly coupled to them, which hampers discoverability, maintainability and testability of the code.
- Objects depend on singletons they don't have any idea which state they're in. The order in which a singleton's behaviors are used here and there starts to become important, and you start seeing "MySingleton.Initialize()"s all over the place, which is dangerous and defeats the whole purpose of having a single instance.

Only singletons that trump these pitfalls are IMO worth considering - that means stateless, immutable objects that somehow get injected into their consumers and can be replaced with other instances with the same contract.

Other than that, Singleton-ification is most often premature optimization applied on the wrong objects.

This blog post pretty much sums it up : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct -- there are cases when single instance is needed. However "avoid singletons" business does not tell that they are not needed. In my understanding it states that singleton behavior should be added by Dependency Container, not by static instance.

That would allow you to mock it in your unittests while having only one instance in production. you may find this link useful: [Object Scopes in Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with singletons and global variables is that we need them but that most programming languages offer only one "global" context.

Imagine that you could do this:

```
 Global g1 = new Global();
 g1.run( ... some code ... );

 Global g2 = new Global();
 g2.run( ... some code ... );
```

When the code is run by `g2`, none of the singletons and globals from the run of `g1` are visible. This is actually what we want: A *efficient* way to say "okay, I'm done with the globals and stuff, **get rid of them**".

The solution is a factory which can build all your singletons and globals for you and put them into the code in the right place. Then you can create new instances of this factory (along with new singletons and globals) in your tests as you need it.

This is what "dependency injection" is all about. Here is a [short introduction](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation).

Comment: Yeah, we use spring's dependency injection but that's not really what concerned me. After all, a singleton is still a global state, no matter how it is created or maintained and I'm just wondering about the vehemence with which they seem to be condemded.

Comment: Global variables in any form have always eventually caused trouble. In today's world, where all code must be thread safe, mutable global state is a either constant danger or a bottleneck. Or to put it a different way: Decentralized organization is more flexible than centralized.